# Select2 Preload and show options together

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying to implement [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) with Laravel for my application.

I'm trying to build a system where users can list their skills (like php, html5, css, etc.).

Works absolutely fine for only select2 with no preload:

```
 <select name="skills[]" 
         data-placeholder="Select Your Skills..." multiple 
         class="select2 form-input col-md-10" 
         id="skills">

        @foreach($skills as $skill)
          <option value="{{$skill->id}}">{{$skill->title}}</option> 
        @endforeach
  </select>                                     
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() { $("#skills").select2(); });
   </script>
```

Or when I try to simply preload options. But the problem starts when I try enable users to edit their skills list. When they go to the edit screen, I want to PRELOAD the skills they already have and then provide them with the available options.

The PRELOAD with select2 working fine with:

```
<input type="hidden" id="skills" style="width:300px;"/>
<script>
    var preload_data = [
     <?php foreach($skills as $skill){ ?>
       { id:<?php echo $skill->id; ?>, text: <?php echo $skill->title; ?>},
     <?php } ?>
    ];

    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#skills').select2({
    multiple: true
    ,query: function (query){
    var data = {results: []};

    $.each(preload_data, function(){
       if(query.term.length == 0 || 
this.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(query.term.toUpperCase()) >= 0 ){
    data.results.push({id: this.id, text: this.text });
    }
    });

    query.callback(data);
    }
    });
    $('#skills').select2('data', preload_data )
</script>
```

So, basically, I'm looking for a solution where I can use this two side by side. The input box will show the existing skills as selected and then the user will be able to select new skills from the list.

This is my Skills Table:

```
--------------------------------------------------
id | title | description | created_at |updated_at
--------------------------------------------------
1  | PHP   |Web Artisans | 2014-03-16 | 2014-03-16
--------------------------------------------------
```

I'd be grateful if anyone can enlighten me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Anyone with an answer or suggestion?

Comment: Did u get around this? 
If not, would please explain better where is the issue related with Select2? If I understood correctly, you are trying to populate a multi-SelectBox where user can select X skills. You want the select to automatically load with Skills/Tags that belong to the user and allow to remove/add skills from this list?